# System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Not able to fetch token for given User

Tags: azure-sql-database, continuous-deployment, dacpac

I am enabling Continuous Deployment of sql dacpac through release definition in Visual studio online. I have used Azure SQL Database Deployment step for DB deployment.

But during the execution of the step I am getting below error:

System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Not able to fetch token for given User.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue for both static and dynamic ip and it got fixed when I changed the Azure Connection Type from "Azure Classic" to "Azure Resource Manager".